# Mini DP compatibility with Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Nvidia GTX1050

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with an Nvidia GTX1050 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 (Kernel 4.15). The laptop has one hdmi port and one mini DP.

I have had a monitor plugged into the laptop via hdmi for a while. I've bought a second monitor to go dual screen. When I plug in a monitor into the mini DP, ubuntu enters low graphics mode and I cannot use the UI.

I have confirmed both monitors work fine individually via hdmi. The problem is specific to the mini DP.

I have tried mini DP to hdmi and mini DP to VGA so far. I'm not sure whether to try any other adapter options (mini DP to DP would be my next try).

I assume I'm missing a driver, but I am not actually sure which driver I am even missing, would it be a graphics card driver?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I opened software updater
- Went to Additional Drivers
- Under Nvidia I had 'Using X.Org X Server' selected
- I changed this to 'Using Nvidia driver.. (proprietary)' and it everything works